# How to accept CloudKit shares with the new SwiftUI app lifecycle?

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

In the iOS 13 world, I had code like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
        func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShare.Metadata) {
                // do stuff with the metadata, eventually call CKAcceptSharesOperation
        }
}
```

I am migrating my app to the new SwiftUI app lifecycle, and can’t figure out where to put this method. It used to live in AppDelegate pre-iOS13, and I tried going back to that, but the AppDelegate version never gets called.

There doesn’t seem to be a SceneDelegateAdaptor akin to UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor available, which would provide a bridge to the old code.

So, I’m lost. How do I accept CloudKit shares with SwiftUI app lifecycle?

Comment: There is no one. Submit feedback to Apple, maybe they will include it till release... and, probably, it is not time for yet to migrate to SwiftUI life-cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use AppDelegate with SwiftUI's new life-cycle until Apple releases APIs to handle this natively in SwiftUI’s App Life-cycle.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

[Read this for more](https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftuis-new-app-lifecycle-and-replacements-for-appdelegate-and-scenedelegate-in-ios-14-c9cf4a2367a9)

Comment: Some methods of AppDelegate are called, but not all. In iOS 13, some callbacks moved from AppDelegate to SceneDelegate. In iOS 14 with SwiftUI, neither AppDelegate nor SceneDelegate version of `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` seems to be called.

Comment: @Jaanus is there a workout around? I have the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541441/using-uiapplicationdelegateadaptor-to-get-callbacks-from-userdidacceptcloudkitsh

Comment: The only workaround that I know is to keep using UIKit app lifecycle until this gets fixed in iOS SDK. (It works fine in AppKit with SwiftUI lifecycle, but not UIKit.)