# Using UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor to get callbacks from userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith not working

Tags: swift, swiftui, icloud, cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

I'm trying to get notified when `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` gets called.  Traditionally this was called in the `App Delegate` but since I am building an iOS 14+ using `App` as my root object.  I couldn't find any documentation out yet as far as how to add `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` to my App class, so I am using `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` to use an `App Delegate` class, however it doesn't seem like `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` is ever getting called?

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit

// Our observable object class
class ShareDataStore: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = ShareDataStore() 
    @Published var didRecieveShare = false
    @Published var shareInfo = ""
}

@main
struct SocialTestAppApp: App {
    
    
    @StateObject var shareDataStore = ShareDataStore.shared 
    
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(shareDataStore)
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.TestApp")
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("did finish launching called")
        return true
    }
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShare.Metadata) {
        print("delegate callback called!! ")
        acceptShare(metadata: cloudKitShareMetadata) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let recordID):
                print("successful share!")
                ShareDataStore.shared.didRecieveShare = true
                ShareDataStore.shared.shareInfo = recordID.recordName
            case .failure(let error):
                print("failure in share = \(error)")
            }
        }    }
    
    func acceptShare(metadata: CKShare.Metadata,
                     completion: @escaping (Result<CKRecord.ID, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        // Create a reference to the share's container so the operation
        // executes in the correct context.
        let container = CKContainer(identifier: metadata.containerIdentifier)
        
        // Create the operation using the metadata the caller provides.
        let operation = CKAcceptSharesOperation(shareMetadatas: [metadata])
        
        var rootRecordID: CKRecord.ID!
        // If CloudKit accepts the share, cache the root record's ID.
        // The completion closure handles any errors.
        operation.perShareCompletionBlock = { metadata, share, error in
            if let _ = share, error == nil {
                rootRecordID = metadata.rootRecordID
            }
        }
        
        // If the operation fails, return the error to the caller.
        // Otherwise, return the record ID of the share's root record.
        operation.acceptSharesCompletionBlock = { error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else {
                completion(.success(rootRecordID))
            }
        }
        
        // Set an appropriate QoS and add the operation to the
        // container's queue to execute it.
        operation.qualityOfService = .utility
        container.add(operation)
    }
    
    
}
```

Updated based on Asperi's Answer:

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit

class ShareDataStore: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = ShareDataStore() 
    
    @Published var didRecieveShare = false
    @Published var shareInfo = ""
}

@main
struct athlyticSocialTestAppApp: App {
    
    
    @StateObject var shareDataStore = ShareDataStore.shared 
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    let sceneDelegate = MySceneDelegate()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(shareDataStore)
                 .withHostingWindow { window in
                 sceneDelegate.originalDelegate = window.windowScene.delegate
                 window.windowScene.delegate = sceneDelegate
              }
        }
        
    }
    
}


class MySceneDelegate: NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com...")
    
     var originalDelegate: UIWindowSceneDelegate?

        var window: UIWindow?

        func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
            print("scene is active")
        }

        func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
            print("scene will resign active")
        }
        
    
      // forward all other UIWindowSceneDelegate/UISceneDelegate callbacks to original, like
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    originalDelegate?.scene!(scene, willConnectTo: session, options: connectionOptions)
   }

        func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShare.Metadata) {

            print("delegate callback called!! ")
            acceptShare(metadata: cloudKitShareMetadata) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let recordID):
                    print("successful share!")
                    ShareDataStore.shared.didRecieveShare = true
                    ShareDataStore.shared.shareInfo = recordID.recordName
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("failure in share = \(error)")
                }
            }

        }

}


extension View {
    func withHostingWindow(_ callback: @escaping (UIWindow?) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(HostingWindowFinder(callback: callback))
    }
}

struct HostingWindowFinder: UIViewRepresentable {
    var callback: (UIWindow?) -> ()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak view] in
            self.callback(view?.window)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/2206721-application), it seems like it won't get called if you're using scenes, which I think would be the case with `SwiftUI`, but I couldn't find a way to set the window scene delegate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Scene-based` application the `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` callback is posted to Scene delegate, but in SwiftUI 2.0 `App-based` application the scene delegate is used by SwiftUI itself to provide `scenePhase` events, but does not provide native way to handle topic callback.

The possible approach to solve this is to find a window and inject own scene delegate wrapper, which will handle `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` and forward others to original SwiftUI delegate (to keep standard SwiftUI events working).

Here is a couple of demo snapshots based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63276688/12299030 window access (however you can use any other preferable way to get window)

```
@main
struct athlyticSocialTestAppApp: App {
    @StateObject var shareDataStore = ShareDataStore.shared 
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    let sceneDelegate = MySceneDelegate()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(shareDataStore)
              .withHostingWindow { window in
                 sceneDelegate.originalDelegate = window?.windowScene.delegate
                 window?.windowScene.delegate = sceneDelegate
              }
        }
    }
}

class MySceneDelegate : NSObject, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
   var originalDelegate: UISceneDelegate?

   func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShareMetadata) {

       // your code here
   }

   // forward all other UIWindowSceneDelegate/UISceneDelegate callbacks to original, like
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
       originalDelegate?.scene(scene, willConnectTo: session, options: connectionOptions)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm having a problem with the line `sceneDelegate.originalDelegate = window.windowScene.delegate` which the compiler says `Cannot assign value of type 'UISceneDelegate?' to type 'UIWindowSceneDelegate?'` and `window.windowScene.delegate = sceneDelegate` which the compiler says Value of optional type 'UIWindow?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'windowScene' of wrapped base type 'UIWindow` ? I posted an edit to my question with what you suggested above.

Comment: It's obvious, just change what compiler asked. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question that has a lot of useful things to check across several possible answers:

[CloudKit CKShare userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith Never Fires on Mac App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827303/cloudkit-ckshare-userdidacceptcloudkitsharewith-never-fires-on-mac-app)

Be sure to add the `CKSharingSupported` key to your info.plist, and then try putting the `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` in different places using the answers in the above link (where you put it will depend on what kind of app you're building).

Comment: Thanks, yes I do have `CKSharingSupported` and had come across that question as well.  My app is an iOS app, built for iOS 14 so I didn't have an `appDelegate` or `sceneDelegate` to start with but as in my question I have tried to use `appDelegateAdapter` which works but `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith` doesn't get called.  I've also tried all the steps suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57104025/userdidacceptcloudkitsharewith-not-being-called to add a `sceneDelegate` but it never gets called there either.

Comment: For what it's worth, I found `CKShare` to be really difficult to work with. You might consider doing your own sharing by using the `Public` database of your app. You could put records in there that a user wants to share and then they are instantly available to other people using your app without the hassle of managing the `CKShare` permissions. Just a thought.