# How to get appdelegate like thing in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appdelegate

I am converting my UIKit app to SwiftUI app, in my UIKit project I am passing some url to webview and getting some result (dynamic url) then below appdelegate method gets call

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

but same thing I want to implement in SwiftUI and not sure what approach is there for this kind of thing in SwiftUI.

It will be great help if I get some pointer or code for same.

Thank You for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor to get callbacks from userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541441/using-uiapplicationdelegateadaptor-to-get-callbacks-from-userdidacceptcloudkitsh)

Comment: https://mokacoding.com/blog/how-to-migrate-from-swiftui-to-uikit-life-cycle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom class that conforms to `UIApplicationDelegate`, and then use the `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` to tell your SwiftUI app about it:

```swift
class MyAppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // your code here
  }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(MyAppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```